# Rename/Change label in a Forest Plot

Tags: r, plot

I have the following model which I want to plot nicely via the "plot_model" function:

```
 ols4 <- feols(instrastate_war_recurrence ~ Governance.Score + log(1+conflict_cntr_count_region_7_l1) + log(gdppc_out) |time_since_conflict,data=data1)
```

I tried the following:

```
forestmodel <- plot_model(ols4, labels =c("Governance Score", "Conflict in Region", "GDP per Capita"), type = "est", title = "Effects on Intrastate War Recurrence", show.values = "TRUE", digits = 4, show.p = TRUE, show.legend = TRUE)
```

And got the following:

[image]

How can I rename/change the labels of the variables ***"(1+conflict_cntr_count_region_7_l1)"*** and ***"gdppc out (log)"*** in the forest plot?

Thanks in advance :)

Data (Excel sheet): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nqQajKefmu2dgexQKMMcgsvh70G6aO4G/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=107305854232845923897&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: @Quinten I have added the link to the Excel sheet (via google drive). I hope that helps, thank you :)